# GSSException when running SPNEGO Kerberos with Integrated Windows Authentication

Tags: single-sign-on, kerberos, windows-authentication, spnego, mit-kerberos

I am trying to setup Kerberos Integrated Windows Authentication using spnego and tomcat.

This is first time I am doing this and have not seen a real enviornment so relying on online documentation mostly the spnego site.
I am getting below error:

> GSSException: Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level:
>   Invalid Argument (400) Cannot find key of appropriate type to decrypt
>   AP REP - RC4 with HMAC)

```
Catalina log shows:
Jan 30, 2017 10:12:37 AM net.sourceforge.spnego.SpnegoHttpFilter doFilter
SEVERE: HTTP Authorization Header=Negotiate <edited - actual had a big key>
Jan 30, 2017 10:41:24 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8443"]
Jan 30, 2017 10:41:24 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
```

Attaching my krb5 and login.conf.

[krb5.conf](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ao7EjuPx45ITauPCWypr5lzh09A)
[login.conf](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ao7EjuPx45ITawyPiD29eaYYmkM)

```
KLIST command gives 2 keys:
CLIENT: B1GYZDM @ test.win.org
Server: krbtgt/test.win.org @ test.win.org
KerbTicket Encryption Type: RSADSI RC4-HMAC(NT) 

CLIENT: B1GYZDM @ test.win.org
Server: krbtgt/test.win.org @ test.win.org
KerbTicket Encryption Type: AES-256-CTS-HMAC-SHA1-96
```

Tomcat is running as local-service. 
And keytab supports 128 & 256 encryption.

Can you please help me resolve the issue?

```
KRB5.conf:
[libdefaults]
default_tkt_enctypes = aes128-cts aes256-cts
default_tgs_enctypes = aes128-cts aes256-cts
permitted_enctypes   = aes128-cts aes256-cts

[realms]
test.win.org  = {
    kdc = test.win.org 
    default_domain = test.win.org 
}

[domain_realm]
test.win.org = test.win.org


login.conf:
spnego-client {
com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required;
};

spnego-server {
com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
storeKey=true
useKeyTab=true
keyTab="file:///E:/Apps/apache-tomcat-7.0.40/bin/test.keytab"
isInitiator=false;
};

custom-client {
com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
storeKey=true
useKeyTab=true
keyTab="file:///E:/Apps/apache-tomcat-7.0.40/bin/test.keytab"
principal=B1ADPST000;
};
```

Comment: Please paste the contents of krb5.conf and login.conf directly into the question itself.  Don't make us go to another site to download them.  Those files are short enough where you can do that.  Well, definitely krb5.conf anyway, for login.conf, you can show the relevant SPNEGO section or the whole thing if it's not much longer than krb5.conf.

Comment: I have updated the ticket with the file contents

Comment: Are you using Microsoft Active Directory fro Kerberos?  Do you still have a copy of the keytab creation syntax you created the keytab with and if so can you also post that?

Comment: Yes its using AD for kerberos. I dont have keytab command but have asked for command to admin will provide if I get it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you get the error when you access the webapp..

Most likely the keytab file does not have a matching key entry.

You should use '/crypto all' when creating the keytab file.

You may run 'klist' on client side, not server side and check the service ticket the client obtained from the KDC for the service (host where the WebApp is deployed), not the 'ticket granting ticket (TGT)'

Comment: As per the admin 'crypto al' cannot be used as it is a significant security vulnerability in org. the klish command was run on client side and the 2 tickets that were presented I put them in this question.

Comment: I would be very interested in that 'security vulnerability' .... the 'klist' output already shows an 'RSADSI RC4-HMAC(NT) ' for the TGT, so what's the issue? If 'unsecure' ciphers are not to be used the AD admin should configure AD accordingly.

'klist' output does not show a service ticket, only ticket granting tickets, hence the browser can not send one to your service/app.

Comment: sorry I missed adding one more ticket which is also shown by klist:
CLIENT: B1GYZDM @ test.win.org
Server: HTTP/br1twvfsg005.test.win.org @ test.win.org
KerbTicket Encryption Type: RSADSI RC4-HMAC(NT)

Comment: and how does the output of `ktutil` from the keypass file looks like?

Comment: the admin created the keytab so I am not aware of the command used. Is there any checks I can do to ensure that the environment is correctly setup?

Comment: if you have access to the keypass file you can use ktutil (https://linux.die.net/man/8/ktutil)
`ktutil -k PATH_TO_keypass_FILE list --keys`

Comment: Is Active Directory being used here?  Looks like it is simply based on the encryption type shown: RSADSI RC4-HMAC(NT).  Please confirm.

Comment: sorry Heron for late reply but I am not sure of the encryption type used in AD. But yes it used AD for sure. The admin told me it is AES 256 encryption is there any way I can confirm?